# Why I cant delete or rename my first user in Ubuntu

Tags: delete

So my user is passw when first time download the Ubuntu, then I accidentally made my first username is passw. When Im trying to delete the passw it always said Removing user `passw' ... Warning: group` passw' has no more members.
userdel: user passw is currently used by process 111
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/sbin/userdel passw' returned error code 8. Exiting.

and I already tried to kill process 111 or kill 111 but still cant delete the first user that named passw

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not clear. First, which version of Ubuntu are you using? Second, what exact command did you try? Have you created another user, let's say called `ernesto`? Have you logged out as `passw` and logged in as `ernesto`? Does `ernesto` have admin abilities?  [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508200/edit) and add all these information.

Comment: Have you created a new user, and are you logged in as this user ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there might be a process running under the user "passw," preventing you from deleting it. Here's a step-by-step guide to resolving this:

Identify the Process: You've already tried to kill process 111, but it seems it didn't work. You can try the following command to see which process is associated with the user "passw": `ps -aux | grep passw`

This command will list all processes containing the term "passw" in their details.

Kill the Process: Once you've identified the process associated with the user "passw," you can try to kill it using the kill command followed by the process ID (PID). For example: `sudo kill -9 [PID]`
Replace [PID] with the actual process ID you found in step 1.

Delete the User: After killing the process, try to delete the user "passw" again using the userdel command: `sudo userdel -r passw`
The -r flag removes the user's home directory and mail spool, which is usually what you want when deleting a user.

Verify Deletion: Finally, verify that the user "passw" has been deleted by listing the users: `cat /etc/passwd`
You should not see "passw" listed anymore.

**If you're still logged in as the user "passw"** you won't be able to delete it while you're actively using it. You'll need to switch to another user account or log out completely.

Here's what you can do:

Switch Users: If you have another user account on the system, switch to that account using the su (switch user) command: `su [another_username]`

Replace [another_username] with the username of the account you want to switch to.

Log Out: If you don't have another user account, you'll need to log out of the "passw" user account: `exit`
This command will log you out of the current user account and return you to the login screen.

Once you've switched to another user account or logged out, you can try deleting the "passw" user again using the userdel command as mentioned earlier: `sudo userdel -r passw`

Ensure that you're running this command with sudo privileges to delete the user.

If you're unable to switch users and still logged in as the user "passw," and killing the processes associated with "passw" didn't resolve the issue, you might need to take additional steps to ensure a clean logout and deletion of the user. Here's a more thorough approach:

Log out of User "passw": Ensure that you're not running any critical processes or applications under the User "passw." Save any work and close all applications.

Force Logout: Open a terminal window and use the following command to force logout the user "passw": `sudo pkill -KILL -u passw`

This command forcefully terminates all processes associated with the user "passw," including the login session.

Verify Logout: Confirm that you've successfully logged out of the user "passw" by attempting to log in again with the new user credentials.

Delete the User: Once logged out, proceed to delete the user "passw" using the userdel command: `sudo userdel -r passw`

The -r flag removes the user's home directory and mail spool.

Verify Deletion: Check that the user "passw" has been deleted by listing the users: `cat /etc/passwd`

You should not see "passw" listed anymore.

Set New User as Main User: If you want to make "ernestosokolov" the main user, you may need to adjust user settings or create a new user with administrative privileges and modify system settings accordingly. This might involve changing settings in the user management tools or modifying the system configuration files.

After following these steps, the user "passw" should be successfully deleted, and you should be able to log in as "ernestosokolov" without any issues. If you encounter any further problems or need assistance with setting up a new main user, feel free to ask.

Comment: it always says process exited with code 9 (0x00000009) and I still logged in into my first user

Comment: I update My Answer with a Solution

Comment: Switching to another user won't work. You have to log out of the user `passw` and login as the new user. Only then there will be no processes running under `passw`.

Comment: @AlyAhmedAly I still got stuck [process exited with code 9 (0x00000009)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart. after I restart it still logged in into the main user, I can't made the ernestosokolov user to be the main user

Comment: I update My Answer again with a Solution

Answer (score -1):

1. Create another user with sudo rights.
2. Logout from passw user and login with new user.
3. Try to delete passw user.

Let me know the output in case of error.